# change onRegistered method to JSONObject in android

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing a gcm notification in my project. I have been able to do every except for the GCM Intent service class. Below is my GCMIntent

```
 public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     * @return 
     * @return 
     **/
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {
         Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + regId);
         UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
         JSONObject json= userFunction.registerUser(context,  RegisterUser.password,regId);
        return json;

    }
```

}

My problem is the `onRegistered` method, it indicates a json error

> change method return to 'JSONObject'

Please how can I solve this problem. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Please below is my UserFunctions class

```
     /**
      * Function to  Register
      **/
    public JSONObject registerUser(Context context, String password,String regId){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regId", regId));

        //GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Share code for UserFunctions

Comment: @Pankajkumar  UserFunctions has been added. Check from the question above

Comment: Sounds almost like you're importing two different classes named JSONObject. It fails to compile right?